# Add a conditional in the reactjs rendering

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that returns me a data that I want to display.

However I would like to add a conditional that would allow me to display my table only if it contains data.

We must use the `if` and `else` conditional for the display of the table.

Is there another solution to not display the map when it is empty?

```
import React from 'react';
import {Card, Col, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';

function Int(props: any) {
    let calendarPlanned: any[] = props.calendarPlannedData;

    return (
    <Card>
        <Card.Body>
           {calendarPlanned.map((planned) => (
                <Col xs={12} lg={12} className="no-gutters" key={planned.id}>
                    <Row>
                        <Col
                            xs={3}
                            lg={3}
                            className="no-gutters"                             
                        >
                            {planned.plannedDate}
                        </Col>
                        <Col
                            xs={2}
                            lg={2}
                            className="d-flex"
                        >
                        </Col>
                        <Col
                            xs={7}
                            lg={7}
                            className="d-flex"
                        >
                            <strong
                                className="d-block text-truncate"          
                            >
                               {planned.stepName}
                            </strong>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Col>
            ))}
        </Card.Body>
    </Card>
   );
}

export default Int;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional rendering by checking `array.length > 0` to render the table as follows.

```
import React from "react";
import { Card, Col, Row } from "react-bootstrap";

function Int(props: any) {
  let calendarPlanned: any[] = props.calendarPlannedData;

  return (
    <Card>
      <Card.Body>
        {calendarPlanned.length > 0 &&
          calendarPlanned.map((planned) => (
            <Col xs={12} lg={12} className="no-gutters" key={planned.id}>
              <Row>
                <Col xs={3} lg={3} className="no-gutters">
                  {planned.plannedDate}
                </Col>
                <Col xs={2} lg={2} className="d-flex"></Col>
                <Col xs={7} lg={7} className="d-flex">
                  <strong className="d-block text-truncate">
                    {planned.stepName}
                  </strong>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </Col>
          ))}
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  );
}

export default Int;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if data exists and if exists it it's length is greater than 0 then render your stuff else just render nothing

```
 {calenderPlanned && calendarPlanned.length > 0 ? calendarPlanned.map((planned) => (....) : null}
```

Comment: Make the last update explaining what you have done. Code-only answers are usually downvoted. Just a suggestion =)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `length` property or just check if `calenderPlanned` has at least one element:

```
{calendarPlanned.length > 0 && calendarPlanned.map((planned) => (....))}
```

Or

```
{calendarPlanned[0] && calendarPlanned.map((planned) => (....))}
```

Of course this is valid if and even if `calendarPlanned` is already defined. If `props.calendarPlannedData` could be `undefined`, you should modify your condition in this way:

```
{calendarPlanned && calendarPlanned.length > 0 && calendarPlanned.map((planned) => (....))}
```

Or

```
{calendarPlanned && calendarPlanned[0] && calendarPlanned.map((planned) => (....))}
```